# How can I get a pid of the foreground app in memory safe way?

Tags: go

I want to get a pid of the foreground app. Please do not recommend [robotgo](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo), I already tried and know that it works but causes memory leak as I commented on [issue](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo/issues/168). Like the code mentioned there I want to get a pid in a loop so it should be memory safe.

Comment: As mentioned I want to get a pid of the active app, or foreground app in other words. For example if I activate chrome I want to get chrome's pid.

Comment: For linux or darwin? If I understand your problem correctly, you just want the active pids (at every "d" duration); right?

Comment: For darwin and you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the following program should help. I'm using the `mitchellh/go-ps` package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"

    ps "github.com/mitchellh/go-ps"
)

func foreground(pid int) (bool, error) {
    out, err := exec.Command("/bin/ps", "-o", "stat=", "-p", strconv.Itoa(int(pid))).Output()
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    return strings.IndexByte(string(out), '+') != -1, nil
}

func getProcs() error {
    procs, err := ps.Processes()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, p := range procs {
        ok, err := foreground(p.Pid())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v\n", err)
            continue
        }
        if ok {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "pid: %d, process: %s\n", p.Pid(), p.Executable())
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func scheduler(tick chan<- struct{}, every time.Duration) {
    tick <- struct{}{}
    for range time.Tick(every * time.Second) {
        tick <- struct{}{}
    }
}

func main() {
    dur := flag.Duration("every", 10, "interval (in seconds)")
    flag.Parse()
    if *dur <= 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "interval should be more than 0")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    tick := make(chan struct{})
    go scheduler(tick, *dur)
    for range tick {
        if err := getProcs(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v\n", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

I've updated the answer. Now you could print the processes that are running in the foreground. Due to unavailability of procfs in darwin based OS's, we are depending on `ps`. So, using `ps -o stat= -p $PID` gives us a `+` sign if the process is running on foreground. So, the theory behind foreground process is that the `process's group id == controlling tty process's group id`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It just lists all process and there's no hint to detect which one is foreground.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Look if it answers your question.

Comment: It only says that terminal processes are active. I tried `sleep 3; ps -A -o stat,command` and brought chrome on top before `ps` is invoked but none of chrome's stat was with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    ps "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process"
)

func getProcs() error {
    procs, err := ps.Processes()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, p := range procs {
        name, _ := p.Name()
        foreground, _ := p.Foreground()
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "pid: %d,\tprocess: %s ,\tForeground: %v\n", p.Pid, name, foreground)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    for range time.Tick(1 * time.Second) {
        if err := getProcs(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v\n", err)
        }
    }
}
```

It is based on shmsr's answer but a different library that provides more information for process

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/H7lPz5pprb__E)